# Standalone alternativo to Eclipse's TCP/IP Monitor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, monitoring

I'm loving Eclipse's plugin TCP/IP Monitor, it shows full header and body for request and response.

I'd some a tool like this, that would run standalone. Could somebody suggest me one?

I tried Charles Web Monitor, but it's designed only for browsers. I can't configure it for Java clients and for local servers that are accessed externally.

It should work like a proxy. I set one port for each destination I wanna monitor. It receives HTTP request on that port and redirects it unchanged to the destination, logging messages data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Apache TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) has been really helpful for me over the years.

There are a number of other tools called "tcpmon": http://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/, http://java.net/projects/tcpmon

I also used [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/) a few times and quite liked it. For a comparison of the various HTTP proxies written in Java see here: http://proxies.xhaus.com/java/

Comment: Cool, thank you a lot! Is there a way for it to save configs I add to it, so that next time I open those configs will be loaded automatically?

Comment: Apache TCPMon. I tried other 2 and they looked almost the same.

Comment: As I can see it can't do it at all. I took a look on the source and I found the Add button event. I could create a startup code to read a XML file with configs and create tabs from it with saved configs, but the source is kinda complex for me to handle at the moment. But I'll try to implement it in the future.